# Counting system calls

Tags: c, linux, security

I have this .c file that counts the system calls that linux calls.  These are just the main functions.  There were a couple of other things that I had to do, like create an array

unsigned long syscall_counts[345];

and then in another file with some assembly I incremented the array with the command:

```
incl syscall_counts(,%eax,4)

// This function is called each time the application calls read(). It starts the      process of
// accumulating data to fill the application buffer. Return a pointer representing the current
// item. Return NULL if there are no more items.
//
static void *counter_seq_start(struct seq_file *s, loff_t *record_number)
{
  if (*record_number > 347)
  return NULL;
return (void*)s;
}


// This function is called to compute the next record in the sequence given a pointer to the
// current record (in bookmark). It returns a pointer to the new record (essentially, an updated
// bookmark) and updates *record_number appropriately. Return NULL if there are no more items.
//
static void *counter_seq_next(struct seq_file *s, void *bookmark, loff_t *record_number)
{
   unsigned long *temp_b =(unsigned long*) bookmark;
   (*temp_b)++;
   if (*temp_b > 345)
  return NULL;
   return (void*)temp_b;
}


// This function is called whenever an application buffer is filled (or when start or next
// returns NULL. It can be used to undo any special preparations done in start (such as
// deallocating auxillary memory that was allocated in start. In simple cases, you often do not
// need to do anything in this function.
//
static void  counter_seq_stop(struct seq_file *s, void *bookmark)
{

}


  // This function is called after next to actually compute the output. It can use various seq_...
 // printing functions (such as seq_printf) to format the output. It returns 0 if successful or a
 // negative value if it fails.
 //
 static int counter_seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *bookmark)
 {
   loff_t *bpos = (loff_t *) bookmark;

   seq_printf(s, "value: %Ld\n", *bpos);

   return 0;
 }


 // Define the only file handling function we need.
 static int counter_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
 {
    return seq_open(file, &counter_seq_ops);
 }
```

my output is very strange:

[image: sample code output]

Anyone have any idea where the issue is?

Comment: The `^@` looks like it's printing a character whose value is 0. Don't know why it's doing it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think :

```
static int counter_seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *bookmark) {  
    unsigned long *bpos = (unsigned long *) bookmark;  
    seq_printf(s, "value: %Ld\n", *bpos);  
    return 0;
}
```

Or even

```
static int counter_seq_show(struct seq_file *s, void *bookmark) {  
    seq_printf(s, "value: %lu\n", *((unsigned long *)bpos));  
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't fully understood your program but I saw two different ways you cast 'bookmark'. In one function you cast it to be 'unsigned long *' and other you do 'loff_t *' (long int). Ideally they should be the same, but are you doing it this way for some reason ?

HTH